# Southern Praying Mantis Kung Fu - Multiple attacker methodology

Tags: self-defense, kung-fu, multiple-attackers

I heard that Southern Praying Mantis Kung Fu is unique in its methods for dealing with attackers to either side while still facing forward. Is this true and where can I find the appropriate specific drills and tutorials for these side-fighting techniques?

I understand that there is a special way to use your hands and hands to cope with the opponent beside you while your body still faces forward. I think it is done to minimize the time of response to opponents at your side and for multiple attackers (front and side). I would like to know how it works.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean with "*fight from your side without changing the body position*"?

Comment: @Avi: I tried to clear up your question a bit more. Let me know if it goes counter to what you were actually wanting to ask.

Comment: I don't have time to sit down and write up an answer currently, but I've found references to "Choy Li Fut" which is an adaptation of various kung fu forms and is noted as being effective versus multiple attackers and to a "hurricane mantis" motion which looks to be a series of circular motions to ward off attacks while striking in various directions.

Comment: Most SPM styles are actually pretty straight-on oriented, rather than dealing with attackers from the side-on. In fact, no martial art deals well with attackers coming at you from the side instead of straight-on. Most SPM styles focus on straight line motion as you travel on the floor. If there is something special about the way it deals with side-on attackers, I'm missing it. Better get a SPM expert on here. I only dabbled.

Comment: By the way, on that subject, you should probably specify which SPM style you're talking about. There are 5 or 6 main branches of them. Each have a somewhat different look and approach.

Comment: The SPM style is KWONG SAI JOOK LUM

Comment: Ah. That's the one I'm most familiar with. Jook lum gee tong long pai. And it really is a front-on fighting system, with special internal mechanics, the use of the phoenix eye fist to attack vital points, chi-sao drills, throwing, and joint locking. Cool looking style. Very traditional. Difficult for outsiders to understand just looking at it what it's doing and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've studied chow gar for about 1 1/2 years now, and I can't think of any such methods.  Southern mantis, like Wing Chun, is based on centre line theory.  The only advice I can offer for facing multiple opponents is to keep a triangular formation and not to let one get beside you or behind you.

Kicking to the side or rear can be effective, but using your hands as such... not so much.